# xcode swift how to debug why the app is crashing after closing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just started coding with xcode and swift. I built a pretty simple app. 
I run it in the simulator and is working fine. The problem occurs when I simulate the double tap home button and close the app. If I do this the app is not opening again so I have to stop the simulation and run it again. The problem is I don't know when this problem occurred first as I just added some storing variables, so the user cans save the progress, and I had to close the app to see if the stored values are saved. This is working even after I restart the simulation.
So the main problem is how to monitor what is preventing the app to reopen after manually closing it with the double tap home button. So far I didn't need to use any debugging as I could see on the simulator if what I was building was working. Bare in mind it is pretty simple app.
Let me know if any other details are needed.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Breakpoint navigator tab in the left side pane. Click + at the bottom left of the side pane. Click "Add Exception Breakpoint."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, you mean you are seeing Xcode showing crash when you **Terminate** the app from *double tap -> slide and close app*.

This is the default behaviour of the Xcode. You are *closing/terminating* the app hence simulator connection with the Xcode is broken. If you single tap home button app will go to the background and connect is still alive between simulator/device and Xcode and all the variables and initializations will remain as it is.

So, there is a difference between *Terminating* the app and making app go to *Background*.

Comment: I don't see anything about any crash. When I **Terminate** the app and try to reopen it it doesn't open. I need to restart the simulator in order to open the app.